# Dog does not respect me, like or trust me now

Tags: dogs, behavior, training

I've heard that a dog should be willing and happy to do what you ask of them, including opening their mouth or holding onto their paw/s/.  Snoopy has learned to walk easily, but still tries to pull.  He will no longer even make eye contact with me unless he wants something.  Sure he obeys basic rules, but it has always been rare that his ears were always forward and naturally and at-peace open and extended.

I know after reading some more, that I was too harsh and scary to him when trying to train him to walk.  I just want to know that he might be able to respect and trust me again, otherwise what is the point of keeping him.  I have worked with him for over a year, closer to two and all along I think he has only only tolerated me.  I am re-examining my tones and body language, emotions, etc. but I just want a dog to trust and do so willingly w/o me so loudly giving a command that the neighbors windows rattle just to get his attention, like looking up at my face (eyes particularly) to acknowledge that he is with me before we can move forward.

I know how to modify my behaviors, but that is not going to do anything to regain his trust and respect.  He will usually show his belly to me, generally willingly, now he will unprompted still, but more out of fear I am thinking.  One would think that I have physically assaulted him.  I am sure I will get an answer or two, but mainly just typing out my frustrations.

How can I regain his trust?

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange! Can you clarify what exactly you are asking?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you think you can take better care of your dog than you have up to this point.

I would like to suggest to you to find a dog obedience class and or dog trainer. That are the kind of people that can help you a lot to get a better relation with your dog.